# Prolog Basic Recursive Division

Tags: math, prolog

I am new to Prolog and am having some difficulty fixing the errors of my first program.

The program requirement is that it divides the 2 inputs using recursion, returning 0 if the dividend is larger than the divisor, and ignores remainders.

```
%Author: Justin Taylor

testquotient :-
    repeat,

    var(Divident), var(Divisor), var(Answer), var(End),

    write('Enter Divident: '),
    read(Divident),

    write('Enter Divisor: '),
    read(Divisor),

    quotient(Divident, Divisor, Answer),
    nl,
    write('Quotient is = '),
    write(Answer),
    nl,

    write('Enter 0 to quit, 1 to continue: '),
    read(End),

    (End =:= 0),!.

    quotient(_, 0, 'Undefined').
    quotient(0, _, 0).
    quotient(Divisor == Divident -> Answer = 1).
    quotient(Divisor < Divident -> Answer = 0).

quotient(Divident, Divisor, Answer) :-
    (Divisor > Divident -> Divisor = Divisor - Divident,
    quotient(Divident, Divisor, Answer + 1);
    Answer = Answer).
```

Comment: What are the errors that need fixing?

Answer (score 1):

First, read up on `is`. Type `help(is).` at the SWI-Prolog's prompt. Read the whole section about "Arithmetic" carefully. Second, your first few clauses for `quotient` are completely off-base, invalid syntax. I'll show you how to rewrite one of them, you'll have to do the other yourself:

```
%% WRONG: quotient(Divisor == Divident -> Answer = 1).
quotient(Divisor, Divident, Answer) :-
    Divisor =:= Divident -> Answer = 1.
%% WRONG: quotient(Divisor < Divident -> Answer = 0).
....
```

Note the use of `=:=` instead of `==`.

Your last clause for `quotient` looks almost right at the first glance, save for the major faux pas: prolog's unification, `=`, is *not*, repeat **not**, an assignment operator! We don't change values assigned to logical variables (if `X` *is* 5, what's there to change about it? It is what it is). No, instead we define *new* logical variable, like this

```
( Divisor > Divident -> NewDivisor = Divisor - Divident,
```

and we use *it* in the recursive call,

```
%% WRONG: quotient(Divident, NewDivisor, Answer + 1) ;
```

but this is wrong too, w.r.t. the new `Answer`. If you add `1` on your way down (as you subtract `Divident` from your `Divisor` - btw shouldn't it be the other way around?? check your logic or at least swap your names, "divisor" is what you divide *by* ) that means you should've supplied the initial value. But you seem to supply the terminal value as `0`, and that means that you should build your result on your way back up from the depths of recursion:

```
%%not quite right yet
quotient(Divident, NewDivisor, NewAnswer), Answer = NewAnswer + 1 ;
```

Next, `Answer = Answer` succeeds always. We just write `true` in such cases.

Lastly, you really supposed to use `is` on each recursion step, and not just in the very end:

```
( Divisor > Divident -> NewDivisor is Divisor - Divident,           %% use "is"
  quotient(Divident, NewDivisor, NewAnswer), Answer is NewAnswer+1  %% use "is"
; true ).                                          %% is this really necessary?
```

Your `'Undefined'` will cause an error on `0`, but leave it at that, for now. Also, you don't need to "declare" your `var`s in Prolog. The line `var(Divident), ..., var(End),` serves no purpose.